# Restricting NuGet repositories during build

Tags: msbuild, nuget

We work in an environment where it is not uncommon for developers to setup local repositories within their workspaces as they test and evaluate various alpha packages. More often than not their nuget.configs gets checked along with their code changes which breaks our CI builds. Worse when such builds get submitted to golden build servers it creates more problems since either the build would break there or if the developer used a repository which was visible to the golden build server, the alpha packages would be included in the golden builds.

Is there a way to put in an override that forces NuGet to ignore any config file other than the one in %appdata%? 
Alternatively could there be a way to customize the msbuild targets in the NuGEt power tools package to achieve this?

We work on TFS 2010 and VS 2010/2012 environment and can modify the default build workflows to put in any customizations that might be required during the build process.

Comment: Your best solution is to stop using nuget. The nuget client tools aren't designed for a reliable build environment.

Comment: What makes you say that Greg?

Comment: Because the tool just doesn't work for non-trivial or multi-person projects: http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Done28099t-let-NuGet-break-your-build-with-the-upcoming-PostSharp-3-release.aspx and https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/taking-nuget-to-the-enterprise/. It's far too easy for an arbitrary third party (perhaps one you didn't even realize you _had_ a dependency on) to break you. Nuget's fundamental design just isn't about creating a stable platform of dependencies for you to use.  (And God help you if you make the mistake I did and turn on Package Restore.)

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party here, but hopefully it is of use to someone...

I have worked in a similar environment and to solve this issue we added a local repository (*e.g. c:\localpackages*) to nuget.config in addition to the remote one which was shared by all (incl the build server).  This local repository could then be used by any developer to add  packages they were working on (or wanted to test).

This meant that the nuget.config file would never need to be changed.  This didn't solve the problem completely though, as devs would be able to commit a project file that referenced a package that was installed from the local repository (which usually broke the build).  To solve this we had to change our code review process to check for instances of this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings), you should be able to limit the repositories by specifying them explicitly. The following should only make the official package source active.

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="TestSource" value="C:\Temp" />
</packageSources>
<disabledPackageSources />
<activePackageSource>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
</activePackageSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Disable NuGet source control integration in your solutions by enabling NuGet restore.
2. Use an MsBuild proj file for your builds and add a pre-build stage which restores the packages in the solution from a given list of sources e.g. nuget.org + internal stable NuGet packages source ([command line reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Restore_command)). This should work if there is always a version at least a high as the pre-release version listed in the packages.config file.